# Find row of value zero and add a row count before and after it

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rowcount

Based on the data below:

```
library(tidyverse)

limit <- c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a","b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")

df <- data.frame(limit, group) 

df
```

I'd like to create a new column (NewCol) as follows:

If there is a row where limit = Id, that should be 0 on NewCol. But then I'd like all the rows before 0 to go back in reverse order until the first row of the group, and all the rows after 0 to be counted until the end of the group.

so for example, in that case, for group "a" it should look like

-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 where -6 is the first row and 2 is the 9th row for that group.

This is what I've tried but still not getting what I need

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(Id = seq(1:length(limit))) %>%
  mutate(NewCol = ifelse(limit == Id, 0, NA)) %>%
  mutate(nn=ifelse(is.na(NewCol),
                       zoo::na.locf(NewCol) + cumsum(is.na(NewCol))*1,
                       NewCol))
```

Thank you

Comment: What if there isn't a row where `limit = Id`? Are the limit the same in every group?

Comment: yes all the groups have the same number of rows, the only thing that changes is the position of the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a difference between the `row_number()` and the 'limit' after grouping by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(NewCol = row_number() - limit)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewCol := seq_len(.N) - limit]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df$NewCol <- with(df, ave(seq_along(limit), group, FUN = seq_along) - limit)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base R, we can use `ave` :

```
df$NewCol <- with(df, ave(limit, group, FUN = seq_along) - limit)

#   limit group NewCol
#1      7     a     -6
#2      7     a     -5
#3      7     a     -4
#4      7     a     -3
#5      7     a     -2
#6      7     a     -1
#7      7     a      0
#8      7     a      1
#9      7     a      2
#10     4     b     -3
#11     4     b     -2
#12     4     b     -1
#13     4     b      0
#...
```

Or using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewCol := seq_along(limit) - limit, group]
#Or
#setDT(df)[, NewCol := seq_len(.N) - limit, group]
```